# Can't change Android ImageView's Y in Java file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview

I am trying to make a Helicopter-like game (as you can probably tell, I'm using "Rocket Man" instead of a helicopter). I'm new to Android programming and to Stack Overflow, so don't pick apart my code too much (please). Anyway, right now I'm just trying to get the rocketman to move up while touch is held down, and move down while touch is released.

It isn't working out very well.

I'm using a Moto XT886 for testing, (in case that's relevent). When I run the application, it starts up and loads the MainActivity perfectly well. When I touch the screen the first  time (boolean start == true), the text views are hidden, as they are supposed to. However, on the second, third, fourth and all the rest of the times I touch the screen (Start == false), nothing happens. There are no errors in Log Cat, the code doesn't seem to recognize the touch.

I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with those while loops, but I'm using this application mainly to learn Android Java and I don't know enough (yet) to recognize that I'm doing something wrong. Are you able to put a while loop with the conditions as the MotionEvent of an onTouchListner? Or is it something else?

Either way, I appreciate the help, this is an awesome website (this is the first question I couldn't find already asked on Stack Overflow, and for all I know, mine could've already been answered)!

Here's the code to my MainActivity, if you need the .xml code as well, (though I'm pretty sure that's unnecessary) just say the word.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

boolean Start;
RelativeLayout rLayout;
TextView gameTitle;
TextView clickStart;
TextView highScore;
Handler handler;
ImageView rocketMan;
float Y;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();

    rLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (Start == true) {
                gameTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                clickStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                highScore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Start = false;
            }
            if (Start = false) {
                while (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Y = -7;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            HeliMove();
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
                while (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    Y = 7;
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100);
                                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            HeliMove();
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
}

private void initialize() {
    rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    Start = true;
    gameTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rocketmanTitle);
    clickStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tapToStart);
    highScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highScore);
    handler = new Handler();
    rocketMan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rocketMan);
}

private void HeliMove() {
    rocketMan.setY(rocketMan.getY() + Y);

}
```

}

Thanks a million!